# To what extent should the programmer consider the actions of other when coding?

Tags: java

Say I have the following simple method:

```
public boolean foo(int arg0) {
    if (arg0 <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("arg0 must be greater than zero");
    }

    return bar(arg0);
}
```

If someone were maintaining my code, they could very easy move things around so that the check for `arg0 > 0` isn't the first thing to occur. Is the onus on me as the programmer to design the method so that its inherently clear that the check must come first (such as by putting everything after the check in an else section) or should I not be concerned with this? At what point does the programmer accept that the maintainer will always be able to change things no matter how well coded?

Comment: Write a doc comment with the details if you will. But someone with a programmer's mind will know better.

Comment: You're never writing code for yourself -- always for someone else (or the future version of yourself). This is why considering "others" when coding is one of the most important things in programming.

Comment: If some maintainer breaks your code, it's clearly his/her responsibility. You cannot keep people from screwing up things. Make your intentions as clear as possible, so future developers can easily understand, reducing the chance for them to introduce errors which follow misunderstanding.

Comment: You should always consider others, that goes without saying. Even if that "other" is your future self. The million dollar question is **how much previous knowledge should you assume on their behalf**? In your specific example it is very reasonable to assume that every sensible programmer knows preconditions need to be checked first. (They are **pre**conditions after all.) So no extra explanation is needed. But if you wrote the same code for an entry-level programming tutorial, you'd want to explain it.

Comment: All the other comments are absolutely correct but regarding you question: `at what point does the programmer accept that the maintainer will always be able to change things no matter how well coded.`, I believe your responsibility is finished if your method has the correct `unit tests` that test the behaviors you've decided to implement. This way, if they go around and change your code later, and if they've indeed broken your code, they will immediately find out their mistake by the virtue of a unit test that covers this condition check. Codes can change and the only reliable way to...

Comment: ... validate their behavior is via testing and not via comments and obscure methods. If I were you, I would also change your if test with an assert but that's my own personal preference and won't make much of a difference, except maybe it's clearer that it's a pre-condition but that's just semantics.

Comment: Define 'consider'. If someone is going to break your code, what exactly can you do about it? What's the question?